# Make strings not appear in the same row

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, sql

I'm trying to create an order form where multiple lines can be added and keep things clean.  This issue is when I send it to my DB it combines the lines.  I want each item to be on it's own line.

For example, I want to have the teacher name, submitted by and notes show item1, description1, etc.  The only things that should repeat would be the teacher, submitted and notes.

I've tried everything, but this is a little past my comfort zone!

**My SQL Result**:

[image]

**Picture here of how I would like it**:

[image]

Note: it doesn't seem to like the php's, so it doesn't show completely accurate.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery($ => {
    let $table = $('#articles');
    var id = "id" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2)
    var teachername = $("#txt_teachername").val();
    var submittedby = $("#txt_submittedby").val();
    var notes = $("#txt_notes").val();
    var item = $("#txt_item").val();
    var description = $("#txt_description").val();
    var quantity = $("#txt_quantity").val();
    var vendor = $("#txt_vendor").val();


    $table.on('input', '.teachername, .submittedby, .notes, .item, .description, .quantity, .vendor', function() {
      let $row = $(this).closest('tr');
      var teachername = $row.find('.teachername').val();
      var submittedby = $row.find('.submittedby').val();
      var notes = $row.find('.notes').val();
      var item = $row.find('.item').val();
      var description = $row.find('.description').val();
      var quantity = $row.find('quantity').val();
      var vendor = $row.find('.vendor').val();
    })

    $table.on('click', '.btn-remove', function() {
      if ($table.find('tr').length > 1) // prevent deletion of all rows
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    })

    $table.on('click', '.btn-add', function() {
      let $clone = $table.find('tr:first').clone().appendTo($table);
      $clone.find('.teachername, .submittedby, .notes, .item, .description, .quantity, .vendor').val('');
    });


    if (submittedby != '') {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: {
          teachername: teachername,
          submittedby: submittedby,
          notes: notes,
          item: item,
          description,
          description,
          quantity: quantity,
          vendor: vendor
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',

        //        success: function(){
        success: function(response) {

          $('.details').show();

          // selecting values from response Object
          var teachername = response.teachername;
          var submittedby = response.submittedby;
          var notes = response.notes;
          var item = response.item;
          var description = response.description;
          var quantity = response.quantity;
          var vendor = response.vendor;

          // setting values
          $('#teachername').text(teachername);
          $('#submittedby').text(submittedby);
          $('#notes').text(notes);
          $('#item').text(item);
          $('#description').text(description);
          $('#quantity').text(quantity);
          $('#vendor').text(vendor);
        }
      });
    }
  });
})
```

```css
table tr:first-of-type td:last-of-type button {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.post-header {
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #121433;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 50px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 40px 0 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: double #555;
}

h2 {
  background-color: #121433;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  line-height: 150px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 40px 0 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: double #555;
}

h3 {
  background-color: #121433;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  line-height: 150px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 40px 0 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: double #555;
  border-color: #121433 !important;
}

.form-group {
  background-color: #121433;
}

.teacherinput {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s
}

.form-control-quantity {
  display: block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s
}

.form-control-item {
  display: block;
  width: 190px;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s
}

.form-control-description {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s
}

.rrjeshta {
  background-color: #121433 !important;
}

.all {
  background-color: #121433;
}

.container {
  background-color: #121433;
}

.page {
  background-color: #121433;
}

.table-responsive {
  background-color: #121433;
}

.table-bordered {
  background-color: #121433;
}

body {
  background-color: #121433;
}

head {
  background-color: #121433;
}

hr.style-four {
  height: 12px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 12px 12px -12px rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.75);
}

.quantity {
  background-color: yellow;
}

p {
  color: #bbc3c8;
  font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-indent: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  color: #c64119;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c64119;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #993213;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #993213;
}

.btn-info {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #416cb5;
  border-color: #46b8da
}

.date {
  color: #bbc3c8;
  background: #292929;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -36px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Order Form</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div class="all">
<h1>Order Form</h1>
<form action='getData.php' method="post" class='form'>
<div class="page">
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
    <form name="orders" id="orders">
            <td><input  type="text" id="teachername" name="teachername[]" placeholder="Teacher / Classroom" class="teacherinput" /></td>
            
            <td><input  type="text" id="submittedby" name="submittedby[]" placeholder="Submitted By" class="teacherinput" /></td>
            <br>
            <td><input  type="text" name="notes[]" placeholder="Notes" class="form-control text" /></td>      
      <hr class="style-four">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="articles">
          <tr class="rrjeshta">
            <td><input type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="Item # / ISBN-13" class="form-control-item" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="description[]" placeholder="Item Description" class="form-control-description" /></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Qty" class="form-control-quantity" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="vendor[]" placeholder="Vendor Name" class="form-control vendor" /></td>
            <td><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-add">Add new</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove">X</button></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<hr class="style-four">
<h2>To place an order please be sure to fill out this form as best as you can.<br><br>
You MAY combine as many vendors as you would like on this form!<br><br>
</div>
</body>

</html>

<?php
include "config.php";

$teachername = $_POST['teachername'];
$submittedby = $_POST['submittedby'];
$item = $_POST['item'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$vendor = $_POST['vendor'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];

$foundjquery = "Not found";
if(in_array('jQuery',$teachername)){
    $foundjquery = "found";
}
// Converting the array to comma separated string
$teachername = implode(",",$teachername);
$submittedby = implode(",",$submittedby);
$item = implode(",",$item);
$description = implode(",",$description);
$quantity = implode(",",$quantity);
$vendor = implode(",",$vendor);
$notes = implode(",",$notes);

$count = 1;

$insertquery = "INSERT INTO orderinfo(teachername,submittedby,item,description,quantity,vendor,notes) VALUES('".$teachername."','".$submittedby."','".$item."','".$description."','".$quantity."','".$vendor."','".$notes."')";
mysqli_query($con,$insertquery);

$return_arr = array('teachername'=>$teachername,'submittedby'=>$submittedby,'item'=>$item,'description'=>$description,'quantity'=>$quantity,'vendor'=>$vendor,'notes'=>$notes,"foundjquery"=>$foundjquery);

//echo json_encode($return_arr);


?>

  <html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <body>
    <h3>Your order has been sucessfully submitted!
      <h3>
        <a href="index.php">
          <br>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit another order" />
        </a>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: if i understand you want each order in his own card that's it ?

Comment: I want each item to show on its own row in the database instead of combining as a comma separated string.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add an example of what it should look like? And also an example of how it currently looks with the comma separated string?

Comment: I have an image in the question of how it looks now. The difference would just be each item in its own row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change

```
$teachername = implode(",",$teachername);
$submittedby = implode(",",$submittedby);
$item = implode(",",$item);
$description = implode(",",$description);
$quantity = implode(",",$quantity);
$vendor = implode(",",$vendor);
$notes = implode(",",$notes);

$count = 1;

$insertquery = "INSERT INTO orderinfo(teachername,submittedby,item,description,quantity,vendor,notes) VALUES('".$teachername."','".$submittedby."','".$item."','".$description."','".$quantity."','".$vendor."','".$notes."')";
mysqli_query($con,$insertquery);
```

to

```
$teachername = implode(",",$teachername);
$submittedby = implode(",",$submittedby);
$notes = implode(",",$notes);
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($item); $i++) {
    $curItem = $item[$i];
    $curDescription = $description[$i];
    $curQuantity = $quantity[$i];
    $curVendor = $vendor[$i];

    $insertquery = "INSERT INTO orderinfo(teachername,submittedby,item,description,quantity,vendor,notes) VALUES('".$teachername."','".$submittedby."','".$curItem."','".$curDescription."','".$curQuantity."','".$curVendor."','".$notes."')";
    mysqli_query($con,$insertquery);
}
```

so that for each `$item`, you insert a new row into the database.

Comment: Thanks!  This is almost working correctly.  I still get some errors and now I get a single blank line in my DB on each submission. @RockySims

Comment: PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "teachername" in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ordering\phptest\getData.php on line 4
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "submittedby" in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ordering\phptest\getData.php on line 5
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "item" in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ordering\phptest\getData.php on line 6
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "description" in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ordering\phptest\getData.php on line 7
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "quantity" in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ordering\phptest\getData.php on line 8

Comment: PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "vendor" in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ordering\phptest\getData.php on line 9
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "notes" in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ordering\phptest\getData.php on line 10
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #1 ($pieces) must be of type array, string given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ordering\phptest\getData.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ordering\phptest\getData.php(14): implode()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ordering\phptest\getData.php on line 14

Comment: Sounds like `$_POST` is an empty array. You could try adding `echo $_POST;` after `include "config.php";` to see what `$_POST` actually contains.

Comment: PHP Warning:  Array to string conversion in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ordering\phptest\getData.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 1 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ordering\phptest\getData.php on line 19
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 1 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ordering\phptest\getData.php on line 20
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 1 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ordering\phptest\getData.php on line 21
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 1 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ordering\phptest\getData.php on line 22

Those are the lines that have $curItem, $curDescription, $curQuantity and $curVendor @RockySims

Comment: and line 3 is the echo $_POST;

Comment: I got the errors to go away by simply adding a fallback value on those lines by adding ??""